# resharper inspectcode fails to run

Tags: windows, resharper, command-line-interface

I have recently started using ReSharper (it is installed and is working correctly in VS2012) and i'm looking at the CLI tools for use with some automated testing.

I have downloaded, extracted and tried to run 'InspectCode.exe' but it is throwing a colossal error message:

```
--- EXCEPTION #1/6 [NotSupportedException]
Message = "An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException
ClassName = System.NotSupportedException
HResult = COR_E_NOTSUPPORTED=80131515

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/6 [FileLoadException]
Message = "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\ReSharper Command Line Tools\JetBrains.Platform.DocumentManager.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException
ClassName = System.IO.FileLoadException
InnerException = "Exception #1 at Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_NOTSUPPORTED=80131515
Source = mscorlib
FileLoad_FileName = "file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\ReSharper Command Line Tools\JetBrains.Platform.DocumentManager.dll"
StackTraceString = "
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
     at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
     at JetBrains.Application.Parts.FileBasedPartCatalogueAssemblyBinder.JetBrains.Application.Parts.IPartCatalogueAssemblyBinder.BindToRuntimeAssembly()
"

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #3/6 [InvalidOperationException]
Message = "Could not bind a part catalog assembly by loading from file "C:\Program Files (x86)\ReSharper Command Line Tools\JetBrains.Platform.DocumentManager.dll"."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException
ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException
InnerException = "Exception #2 at Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509
Source = JetBrains.Platform.ComponentModel
StackTraceString = "
  at JetBrains.Application.Parts.FileBasedPartCatalogueAssemblyBinder.JetBrains.Application.Parts.IPartCatalogueAssemblyBinder.BindToRuntimeAssembly()
     at JetBrains.Application.Parts.PartCatalogueAssembly.Bind()
"

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #4/6 [InvalidOperationException]
Message = "Could not load the runtime assembly for the part catalog assembly "Assembly: JetBrains.Platform.DocumentManager, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325"."
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException
ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException
InnerException = "Exception #3 at Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509
Source = JetBrains.Platform.ComponentModel
StackTraceString = "
  at JetBrains.Application.Parts.PartCatalogueAssembly.Bind()
     at JetBrains.Application.Parts.PartCatalogueType.Bind()
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.InitializationStrategyDefault.Schedule(Lifetime lifetime, IComponentDescriptor dsc)
"

--- Outer ---
```

.... (it goes on and on, 44MB of error messages!)

From what google's that have mentioned these errors, nothing has pointed me in the right direction.

Has anyone seen this before and knows what I can do?

Comment: Did you copy the assemblies to another machine from a network share/remote location?  If so, you need to unblock them.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15238782/1698557).

Comment: Lessons learned: Actually read the damn error message! Thanks :D