# How to fix a trust issue

Tags: .net, trust

I have sent an application written in C# to a customer. The application works properly when I run it on my workstation and on other workstations in our office.  But, it does not run successfully on the customer's computer.

When the program (a console application) loads, there is a message about not being able to load an assembly that would have been sandboxed in an earlier version of the .NET framework. This is new to me. I'd never heard of sandboxing before.

From what I've been able to read, the problem seems to be a trust issue of some kind.  There's some setting somewhere on the customer's machine that is preventing the program from loading several DLLs that we wrote that are used by the exe file.

I don't have a clue what to look for or where to look for it.  Can someone tell me what to do or to look for?

Comment: Could be [Code Access Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527276.aspx).

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238714/net-local-assembly-load-failed-with-cas-policy) addresses your problem?

Comment: @DanielKelley Yes, I believe that is the cause of the issue.  But how do I fix it?

Comment: @JoshPart Thanks, I will have the customer give that a try.  That sounds promising

Comment: @JoshPart Thanks, that did it